# Error when using Zlib::Inflate 'invalid distance too far back'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zlib

I have BLOB data in mySQL stored by doing `Zlib deflate`. The storage was done on a machine running ruby 1.8.6 using the mysql gem.

When trying to uncompress the data on a machine running ruby 2.0 and mysql2 gem by using `Zlib::Inflate.inflate(raw_data)` I get a "invalid distance too far back" error from Zlib. Which suggests the compressed data cannot be read by Zlib.

Is there a known way to retrieve and decompress this data or is the only way to decompress on the 1.8.6 machine?

Am I right to look into the ruby and mysql connector versions? or could the issue be rails or linux(zlib) related?

Comment: the data might be corrupted. This error mostly comes with data being corrupted.

Comment: @reijn I can read the data and write a uncompressed version back using the 1.8.6/myslq1 environment

Comment: check the zlib version in which data was compressed.

Comment: Please provide the first 30 bytes of the BLOB data in hexadecimal.

Comment: did you solve your problem ? If yes How ???

Comment: @sam It turned out to be a corrupt data dump if I recall correctly.

Comment: I have same Problem But My file is a Web page witch load in browsers Correctly :(   No advise ?